# add xml attribute "xsi:nil"

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, xml-nil

I am reading the following file in powershell.

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <nested1>
    <level1 xsi:nil="true" />
    <level2>2</level2>
  </nested1>
  <nested2>
    <level1 xsi:nil="true" />
    <level2>2</level2>
  </nested2>
</root>
```

using...

```
[xml]$XmlDoc = get-content $XMLFile
```

I would like to set
$XmlDoc.root.nested1.level2
so it has the attribute xsi:nil="true"

so the file appears as

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <nested1>
    <level1 xsi:nil="true" />
    <level2 xsi:nil="true" />
  </nested1>
  <nested2>
    <level1 xsi:nil="true" />
    <level2>2</level2>
  </nested2>
</root>
```

Many Thanks for any advice offered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `SetAttribute()` and provide the namespace URI.

```
$node = $XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode('//nested1/level2')
$node.SetAttribute('nil', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 'true') | 
    Out-Null
```